# Issues with common pod dependency in cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

So I tried installing Parse iOS SDK along with Facebook SDK and I am getting errors due to non-matching versions of the Bolts dependency. I have the following `cocoapods env`

#### Stack

`CocoaPods : 1.4.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
    RubyGems : 2.5.2
        Host : Mac OS X 10.13.3 (17D102)
       Xcode : 9.2 (9C40b)
         Git : git version 2.14.3 (Apple Git-98)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 0ceca6006fa5a6d42842e7d67324c9fdec36331e`

#### Installation Source

`Executable Path: /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.4.0/libexec/bin/pod`

#### Plugins

`cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.2
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0`

#### Podfile

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

workspace 'MyProject'
project 'MyProject.xcodeproj'
platform :ios, '10.3'

target 'MyProject' do
    use_frameworks!

    # Backend
    pod 'Parse', '1.6'
    pod 'Parse/FacebookUtils'
    pod 'Parse/TwitterUtils'

    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.28.0'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.28.0'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '4.28.0'
end
```

And this is the error that I get when doing `pod install`:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Bolts":
  In Podfile:
    FBSDKCoreKit (= 4.28.0) was resolved to 4.28.0, which depends on
      Bolts (~> 1.7)

    Parse (= 1.6) was resolved to 1.6.0, which depends on
      Bolts (~> 1.1.3)
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Use an old version of the Facebook SDK or use an alternative to Parse that is still being maintained.

Comment: You could, if you like pain, edit one of them to use a modern version of Bolts and have it integrate the pod locally instead of from their repo

Answer (score 1):

try 'pod update Bolts' in this case.